# WSDL Web Service for desktop application

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, netbeans-8

I am working on a desktop application, where the user inputs a word, then its definition is displayed. For this I am using the web service: DictService.
My code runs fine, the only problem i have is that it does not return the definition.

Here is my code:

the "jTextField1" is where the user writes the word.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String str = jTextField1.getText();
    System.out.println(define(str));
}
```

The method define is:

```
private static WordDefinition define(java.lang.String word) {
    com.aonaware.services.webservices.DictService service = new com.aonaware.services.webservices.DictService();
    com.aonaware.services.webservices.DictServiceSoap port = service.getDictServiceSoap();
    return port.define(word);
}
```

For example, when i enter the word "test", the output is: "com.aonaware.services.webservices.WordDefinition@f48725b"

I really do not know how to fix this, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT:

The method outputs a list of definitions, whereas i output only a string.
So i have created a list to store all definitions. And i iterated it to output them.

Here is the code to create the list and output it:

```
 String str = jTextField1.getText();

    List<WordDefinition> definitions = new ArrayList<WordDefinition>(Arrays.asList(define(str)));
    for (int i=0; i< definitions.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(definitions.get(i))); //i get an error here
    }
```

Now the error i get is: "incompatible types: WordDefinition cannot be converted to Object[]"

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The class WordDefinition obviously does not have a nice toString() method. You have to explicitely access a member of the returned value:

```
System.out.println(define(str).getSomeValue());
```

Since I do not know the internals of your framework I cannot give more advice.

Comment: I tried that line and it still did not work. What internals do you wish to know?

Comment: I assume the WordDefinition class has some members which can be accessed. What did not work?

Comment: here is an edit: i noticed that the method define returns a list of definitions. Whereas i only output a string. So i need to output the entire list. But i don't know how to do that.

Comment: By iterating over the list maybe?

Comment: How should I know how to fix your problem if I do not know what the class WordDefintion really is?

Comment: I too do not know what is it, it was generated from the WSDL file. i used this youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76Lncm7oTXg if you go to 4:39 you'll see that the person dragged the method, and it got generated. and those are the steps i followed also. Here's the WSDL URL i used: http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx?WSDL